# Jsoup elements don't show up when calling the .text() method

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I'm making an android app and I wanna web scrape a page with motorcycles. When I had iterated over the elements of that page they got printed with html tags but since I had put `.text()` method, I got everything printed in one line on my terminal. You can check my code down below for a better understanding. Thanks in advance.

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    String title = "";
    try {
        Document document = Jsoup.connect("https://www.hotcars.com/best-motorcycles-for-beginners/").get();
        Elements elements = document.select("div[class=w-website]").select("div[class=w-content]");

        for (Element element : elements.select("section[class=article-body]")) {
            title = element.select("h2").text();
            System.out.print(title);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

If I delete `.text()` from the `title`, then I get my text but with html tags which I don't need.

Comment: "but since i had put .text() method i didn't get anything printed on my terminal." strange, can't reproduce on (non-Android) simple Java app. With above code I am seeing `10 Bonneville T120 Triumph 9 Harley-Davidson Street 500 8 Harley-Davidson Superlow 7 Honda CB1100 Ex 6 Honda Rebel 300 5 Kawasaki Ninja 300 4 Kawasaki Z125 Pro SE 3 Suzuki SV650X 2 Yamaha Bolt Cruiser 1 Yamaha YZF-R3` as one line.

Comment: That's exactly what i get if i run the code with .text()

Comment: "That's exactly what i get if i run the code *with* .text()" isn't that contradiction to what you said in question: "but since i had *put* .text() method *i didn't get anything printed* on my terminal"? Please [edit] the question to clarify that part.

Comment: Yeah you're right, i wanted to say that i don't get what i thought i would. If i run the code with .text() i get everything in one line which is strange but without it i get every element but with html tags.

Comment: Sorry but can you clarify what results ware you expecting? Even if I remove `text()` from `element.select("h2").text()` and will simply call `System.out.println(element.select("h2"));` I will get series of `<h2><span class="item-num">10</span> Bonneville T120 Triumph</h2>
<h2><span class="item-num">9</span> Harley-Davidson Street 500</h2>...` which only hold headers used in article.

Comment: if i use .text(), i expect to see only the titles of motorcycles without html tags.

Comment: Then you probably want to iterate over result of `.select("h2")` and call `text()` on each header individually.

Comment: Yeah but i also need <p> tags at the same time for descriptions of motorcycles. I'm trying to get the titles,descriptions and img links of pictures in order to pass it to the database and use it in my app.

Comment: You can always iterate over elements which you want to use starting from headers. To do so use `.nextElementSibling()` and `.children()`. Check if current tag which you are currently handling is `p` via something like `element.tagName().equalsIgnoreCase("p")`.

Comment: Why would i use `.nextElementSibling()` if i'm iterating over elements?

Comment: Because currently you are only iterating on what you selected which is only `h`. If you want to easily get all `p` which are *after* currently selected `h` then iterating over its siblings looks like one of easier approach.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I managed to fix it and now it works perfectly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following as a starting point to get the desired elements

```
try {
    Document document = Jsoup.connect("https://www.hotcars.com/best-motorcycles-for-beginners/").get();
    Elements h2s = document.select("section[class=article-body] h2");

    for (Element h2 : h2s) {
        String title = h2.text();
        Element img = h2.nextElementSibling().selectFirst("picture").selectFirst("source");
        String imgSrc = img.attr("data-srcset");
        Element p1 = h2.nextElementSibling().nextElementSibling();
        Element p2 = p1.nextElementSibling();
        String discription = p1.wholeText() + System.lineSeparator() + p2.wholeText();
        System.out.println(title);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(imgSrc);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(discription);
        System.out.println("------------------------");
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```